# Android send byte array with image using Retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have a byte array in my application which I get from camera. I need to send it to server using Retrofit2. When I try send it I get SocketTimeoutException. I've tried also send request using browser and all works fine. Here is my retrofit service method for sending:

```
@Multipart
@POST("/userchange/setuserpic")
Call<AuthResponse> setUserPic(@Part("authToken") RequestBody authToken, @Part("userpic") RequestBody picture, @Part("extension") RequestBody extension);
```

I do sending in my service like below:

```
private void handleActionSetUserPic(String authToken, byte[] picture, String extension) {
    RequestBody token = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), authToken);
    RequestBody pic = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), picture);
    RequestBody ext = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), extension);
    Call<AuthResponse> request = mAuthApi.setUserPic(token, pic, ext);
    try {
        Response<AuthResponse> response = request.execute();
        AuthResponse result = response.body();
        Log.i("tag", result.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your image very large? Default retrofit timeouts are extremelly short by default in my opinion..